# How to initialise PySpark on AWS Cloud9

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-cloud9

I want to initialise pyspark version 3.3.1 on aws cloud9 and to read a s3 file path from AWS. But when I run the code, I got this error shown in the image.

I was thinking that there is something wrong with my Pyspark initilisation, and I have tried the code below provided by my colleague but apparently this doesn't work for me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi7nk.png)

My pyspark version is 3.3.1 and hadoop version 3

```bash
pkg_list=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1

pyspark --packages $pkg_list --driver-memory 32G --driver-cores 8 --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 32G --executor-cores 8 --driver-java-options="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/yoongkiat/tempfiles"
```

Comment: If you have access to AWS , I would strongly recommended using EMR or EMR + Notebook for this use case , as EMR takes care of setting up your spark enviornment

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that in some hadoop config file or option that Spark is using, you have a string `64M`, but it's only expecting a number.

The error doesn't say which file, and that's not a value you've provided on the command line, so you'll need to debug the installation on your own. As mentioned in comments, AWS EMR already offers a functional Spark environment.

By the, you cannot use dependencies from different Spark versions; you're running 3.3.1, but trying to add spark-avro for 2.4.4. I'm also not certain you'll need to add hadoop-aws since Spark should have those libraries included out of the box.